# Method toJSONObject of org.json.XML cannot hold capitalized accented letters

Tags: java, json, xml

I'm having an XML to JSON transformation issue. It happens that I'm trying to transform an XML string into a JSONObject using method `toJSONObject` of class `org.json.XML`.

The thing is that such method does not hold accented capital letters during the transformation. For example, if the XML contains the word “HellÓ”, it transforms it to “Helló” in the JSON. It holds the accent, but not the capital letter.

In my code I got:

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;

...

try {
   JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(this.xmlString);
   ...
}
```

Any recommendations to solve this problem using this same library?

Comment: It's likely a bug in the XMLTokener  class (nextEntity). You can try to post an issue at https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java , or even try to fix it and the submit a pull request ... It's a tricky one , best luck.

Comment: Underscore-java library has static method `U.xmlToJson(xml)`. I am the maintainer of the project.